# PyTorch: Dropping part of gradient dependence

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm building a probabilistic model `q_{phi)(x)`, which samples points and returns the corresponding likelihood simultaneously. A simple Gaussian example:

```
class NormalModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, mu : torch.Tensor, sigma : torch.Tensor):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.dim_ = mu.shape[0]
        self.mu_ = nn.Parameter(mu, requires_grad=True)
        self.sigma_ = nn.Parameter(sigma, requires_grad=True)

    def sample(self, n_sample):
        eps = torch.normal(mean=torch.zeros(n_sample, self.dim_), std=torch.ones(n_sample, self.dim_))
        sample = self.mu_+ eps*self.sigma_

        log_prob        = -(0.5 * ((sample          - self.mu_)/self.sigma_)**2 + torch.log(self.sigma_) + m.log(2*m.pi)).sum(dim=-1)
        log_prob_detach = -(0.5 * ((sample.detach() - self.mu_)/self.sigma_)**2 + torch.log(self.sigma_) + m.log(2*m.pi)).sum(dim=-1)

        return sample, log_prob, log_prob_detach
```

The sample depdends on the model parameters, `x_{phi}`, and as such the returned `log_prob` depends on the parameters in two ways, `q_{phi}(x_{phi})`. I want to write down a loss function that involves both `q_{phi}(x_{phi})` and `q_{phi}(x)`, i.e. the likelihood where `sample` either does or does not depend on the parameters. I know that I can do this by detaching `sample` before computing the `log_prob`, as is done in the computation of `log_prob_detach` above. This however requires performing the calculation for the `log_prob` twice. Is there some way to accomplish this after the fact, i.e. perform an operation on `log_prob` to obtain `log_prob_detach`?

Comment: If you want `log_prob_detach` to detach only the gradient with respect to `sample` and not the gradient with respect to `self.mu_` or `self.sigma`, this is the way to do it. Logically, there must be a way to detach some variables and not others, and since `log_prob_detach` doesn't specify its dependent variables, how else could those variables be specified?